# WIF - Safari Cookie truncated when used with Azure ACS. Work around in .NET 4.5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, safari, wif, acs

I have an ASP.NET MVC4 application running on Windows Azure and it uses Azure ACS for Federated Authentication.

When we first started testing the application, it was working in all the browsers except Safari and Opera because of the size of cookie.

I've read several articles online that asked me to use FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.IsSessionMode = true;

The above statement will store the data in the cookie on the server side. That fixed the problem because only a session identifier is stored on the client(browser).

However, that attribue appears to be removed from the WIF 4.5 api.

Do you know if there is a work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you save the original token? Do you have something like this in your web.config, or do you set the `saveBootstrapTokens` config setting to true:

```
<securityTokenHandlers>
    <securityTokenHandlerConfiguration saveBootstrapTokens="true" />
</securityTokenHandlers>
```

If you do, or if you don't, try setting the `saveBootstrapTokens` to `false`! This is will save you a lot of "space".

I had this issue only when I had `saveBootstraptokens` set to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - @astaykov is correct - that's part of it.

As per @Dominick, it's called "IsReferenceMode" in .NET 4.5.